# How can we call 2 different packages in main program of pl/sql

Tags: plsql

Question: How can we call 2 different packages in main program of pl/sql

package 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp1_pkg AS 
PROCEDURE update_emp_details(p_ch varchar,
                             p_id emp_data.emp_code%type,
                             p_name emp_data.emp_name%type,
                             p_dept emp_data.dept_name%type,
                             p_manager emp_data.manager_name%type
                            );
END emp1_pkg;
```

package2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE asi1_pkg AS 
PROCEDURE update_asi_details(l_ch varchar2,
                             p_id emp_asi.asi_no%type,
                             p_desc emp_asi.asi_desc%type,
                             p_status emp_asi.asi_status%type,
                             p_created emp_asi.created_by%type
                            );
END asi1_pkg;
```

Comment: More details needed. You have created two package specs. What are you trying to do? To call them, you would refer to `emp1_pkg.update_emp_details(...)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you.....  My doubt is cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you miss the basics about PL/SQL etc. What do you mean with "main program of pl/sql".

A PACKAGE consists of a spec and a body. Above you only show the spec. But you would proably call above like this:

```
BEGIN
  emp1_pkg.update_emp_details(p_ch=>'x',p_id=>1,p_name=>'somename',p_dept=>'somedept',p_manager=>'somemanager');
  asi1_pgk.update_asi_details(p_ch=>'x',p_id=>1,p_name=>'somename',p_dept=>'somedept',p_manager=>'somemanager');
END;
/
```